# Postgres case Query issue

Tags: postgresql, case

I am trying to write a postgres query, which is with CASE statement. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT "State" AS x, count("Age Group") AS y from test.smp_state_survey where "State" IN 
(CASE 
        WHEN 'State' = 'State' THEN 'State 1','State 2','State 3'
        WHEN 'State' = 'District' THEN 'State 1'
    END) 
  group by x ORDER BY x,y
```

The above query is showing syntax error at `'State' = 'State'`

Whereas, when I executed the below query, i get the appropriate results:

```
SELECT "State" AS x, count("Age Group") AS y from test.smp_state_survey where "State" IN 
(CASE 
        WHEN 'State' = 'State' THEN 'State 1'
        WHEN 'State' = 'District' THEN 'State 1'
    END) 
  group by x ORDER BY x,y
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

**Edit:**

The value after THEN clause is dynamic and it may contain 1 or more values (From a multi select box). I want the query to be executed as

```
SELECT "State" AS x, count("Age Group") AS y from test.smp_state_survey where "State" IN 
('State 1','State 2','State 3') 
  group by x ORDER BY x,y
```

Which runs exactly fine, but the problem is that CASE is not returning me the required string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query should be like this, i hope this will work for you

```
SELECT  "State" AS x, count("Age Group") AS y from test.smp_state_survey where  
CASE  
        WHEN 'State' = 'State'  THEN  "State" IN  ('State 1' ,'State 3')
        WHEN 'State' = 'District' THEN "State" IN  ('District 1')
    END
  group by x ORDER BY x,y
```

Answer (score 2):

'State' = 'State' is a tautology.
Do you mean "State" = 'State', i.e. the value of the column "State" equal to the string 'State'?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to use `IN`, you can make use of the fact that `IN` accepts either a set *or an array*:

```
SELECT "State" AS x, count("Age Group") AS y
FROM test.smp_state_survey
WHERE "State" IN (CASE
  WHEN 'State' = 'State' THEN ARRAY['State 1','State 2','State 3']
  WHEN 'State' = 'District' THEN ARRAY['State 1']
END) 
GROUP BY x
ORDER BY x,y
```

or use @user1327246's rephrasing where you push the `IN` test into the `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have multiple values for a single case.

Thats the issue

```
WHEN 'State' = 'State' THEN 'State 1','State 2','State 3'
```

Comment: What is exactly your objective when state=state what should the value be ?

Comment: I am not OP. Ankit is an OP. But looking at his condition, he wants to  return all three values (state1,state2,state3) when 'State' = 'State'

Comment: then that should be a single string like 'State 1 State 2 State 3'

Comment: @shamis: I want the output of CASE to be as input of IN so that the query is like -- where "State" IN ('State 1','State 2','State 3')